# Connecting & Uploading WebDav using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, file-upload, webdav

I'm looking to develop an application in vb.net which can connect to a WebDav enabled web server (using WebDav with login credentials) and upload desired files. Could anyone give me an example on how I can accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A good place to start when working with any new protocol on the internet is to look at the RFC, even if you might not have to read through all of it, it's good to have as a reference. You can find one here: [HTTP Extensions for Web Distributed Authoring and Versioning (WebDAV)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918)

After that you can find a sample project at codeproject called [How to Download a File from a WebDAV Server in VB.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/WebDAV_Download.aspx) which might be a good place to start, and hopefully it won't be too difficult to change the downloading to uploading.

Here's a C# [library](http://kvdb.net/projects/webdav/) that seems to support uploading so you should be able to see in there how you do the uploading.